# Weird light emitting from part of mesh

Tags: eevee-render-engine

So part of my wall seems to be emitting light and has an odd whitish color. I've went through and made sure I din't have an extra light or anything. I'm just not really sure what else I need to check out to solve this. Any help would be appreciated. Here are some photos of the front and the back of this. [image: Interior]
[image: Exterior]

Comment: Looks like there's a lot of bleed from the top ... might be a clue

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit mode and then Press "Shift + N" It will Recalculate your Normals of the Mesh
Just Try If it Helps